# Date Diff Between two Columns

Tags: sql-server, date

Please can you help with the following query regarding the Difference between two dates.

My current table is combined with plenty of columns, however I would like to add another column to identify the date difference.

Two of the columns within the table should be compared and the date diff must then populate in the new added column, however no hours, seconds, mill seconds should be taken into account. The query should only count the different date changes.

Columns

```
- ServiceDt    (2014/09/22)
- ServiceToDt
- SettleDt
- ReceiveDt
- AssessDt     (2014/10/01)

- New Column   ( 9 Days)
```

The `New Column` must be updated with the Difference between the `ServiceDt` and `AssessDt`.

The date diff should be counted as 9 days, as 9 different time dates occurred.

Hope any of the above makes sense. I have tried so many queries and cant give you even one example as non of them worked.

Thank you.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(DAY, FromDate, ToDate)`

Comment: I would not recommend you to create a new column for storing the difference of days among two existing column. Because whenever you needed, you can simply use the query.

Comment: be more spacific.you want to add column to the report or to your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use: `DATEDIFF(DAY, FromDate, ToDate)`

```
SELECT
    *,
    NewCol = DATEDIFF(DAY, ServiceDt, AssessDt)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

use calculate column

```
  ALTER TABLE tbl
ADD DATE_DIFFS AS DATEDIFF(DAY, ServiceDt , AssessDt)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the different methods on how to go about it, I will be testing all the different queries, however, the first answer already provided me with what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not add a computed column, the data is already there. You could create a view. This would contain the same information.

```
CREATE VIEW v_yourview as
SELECT 
  ServiceDt,
 ServiceToDt,
 SettleDt,
 ReceiveDt,
 AssessDt,
 DATEDIFF(DAY, ServiceDt, AssessDt) difference
FROM yourtable
```

If you want the extra column for performance reasons. Create a PERSISTED computed column. This will work like a normal column when creating indexes.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
ADD cDifference as DATEDIFF(DAY, ServiceDt, AssessDt) PERSISTED
```